# error refreshing JPA Entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, stack-overflow, composite-key

I have the following domain model

```
Currency ----< Price >---- Product
```

Or in English

> A Product has one or more Prices. Each Price is denominated in a particular Currency.

`Price` has a composite primary key (represent by `PricePK` below) which is composed of the foreign keys to `Currency` and `Product`. The relevant sections of the JPA-annotated Java classes are below (getters and setters mostly omitted):

```
@Entity @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Currency {

    @Id 
    private Integer ix;

    @Column 
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pricePK.currency", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private Collection<Price> prices = new ArrayList<Price>();
}

@Entity @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Product {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pricePK.product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private Collection<Price> defaultPrices = new ArrayList<Price>();
}

@Embeddable
public class PricePK implements Serializable {

    private Product product;    
    private Currency currency;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    public Product getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    public Currency getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }    
}

@Entity @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Price {

    private PricePK pricePK = new PricePK();

    private BigDecimal amount;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public BigDecimal getAmount() {    
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(BigDecimal amount) {    
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    public PricePK getPricePK() {
        return pricePK;
    }    

    @Transient
    public Product getProduct() {
        return pricePK.getProduct();
    }

    public void setProduct(Product product) {
        pricePK.setProduct(product);
    }

    @Transient
    public Currency getCurrency() {
        return pricePK.getCurrency();
    }

    public void setCurrency(Currency currency) {
        pricePK.setCurrency(currency);
    }
}
```

When I try to [refresh](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#refresh%28java.lang.Object%29) an instance of `Product`, I get a StackOverflowError, so I suspect there's some kind of cycle (or other mistake) in the mapping above, can anyone spot it?

Comment: +1, nicely posed question. I'm curious about the domain model, though. It seems strange that a `Price` is uniquely identified by the `Product`+`Currency` rather than, say, its (scalar) value + `Currency`.

Comment: Thanks Matt, there is actually a `BigDecimal amount` field in the `Price` class too, but I omitted it here because it's not relevant to the question, and I wanted to keep the code listing as short as possible

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this error a few times, but I can't remember the exact solution. I have the idea that you need to remove mapping from PricePK (both @ManyToOne) and replace that with @AssociationOverrides on Price.

```
@Entity @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@AssociationOverrides({
    @AssociationOverride(name = "pricePK.product", 
                         joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")),
    @AssociationOverride(name = "pricePK.currency", 
                         joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "currency_id"))
})
public class Price extends VersionedEntity {
    [...]
}
```

please check that the column names are ok, as I can't see the id columns on Product or Currency.

Comment: @Don Have you tried this solution? Also, I didn't express myself correctly, the *column names* that I mentioned are the names of the columns on Price. So I assumed that on the Price table you have two columns named **product_id** and **currency_id.**

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it caused this error: `Could not determine type for: com.example.Currency, at table: PRICE, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(currency)]`

Comment: @Don, are you able to load one of these entities with EntityManager.find(pk), or does the error only happen with refresh? I remembered where I've seen this before, and it was a similar case, in which there was a cyclic dependency in the Entity instantiation, and as far as I remember Hibernate only handles dependency loops in many to many relationships. I'm sure you'll notice that there's a subtle difference between a *bidirectional relationship* and a *cyclic dependency*.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem and it turned out to be caused by the CascadeType.ALL defined in the OneToMany annotation.  When you refresh product, it is going to try to refresh the prices that are in the persistent context.

Depending on the situation, you may be able to get by without having the prices refreshed when the product is refreshed in the entity manager, such as:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "pricePK.product", cascade = {
        CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE
    }, orphanRemoval = true)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
private Collection<Price> defaultPrices = new ArrayList<Price>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you just declare the relations from Price to Product and Currency as ManyToOne directly in the Price entity, and annotate Price with @IdClass(PricePK)?

I don't know how Hibernate handles this though, but I have successfully implemented this using OpenJPA. In that case, PricePK must declare its fields with the same names as in Price, but using the simple type instead (Integer instead of Currency or Product). In Price, you might need to annotate product and currency with @Id. Note that this is out of the JPA spec (@IdClass only supports simple fields).